# Gurobi out-of-memory issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi

I am working with Gurobi in Python3. When T is around 3000, the following raises a Gurobi "out-of-memory" issue. I don't understand it since I just put empty Gurobi models into a list and the activity monitor doesn't show full memory being used. Plus, changing the thread number to one doesn't help much.

```
m = [None for _ in range(T)]
for t in range(T):
    m[t] = gurobipy.Model()
```

Comment: Commercial product generally have a commercial help line / bug tracker. What do you think SO can do about it? Why don't you do `m = [ gurobipy.Model() for _ in range(T)]` directly? Will probably result in the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this issue by creating each model with a separate gurobi Env objects

```
models = [gurobipy.Model(env=gurobipy.Env()) for _ in range(T)]
```

It is unusual to want so many separate Model objects at once, however.  Even if you are solving many related problems in sequence, it's usually better to modify a model than create an entirely separate one.